# Unable to cast the Linq result to existing pre defined model

Tags: c#, linq

I got the error as below

`cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable WebUI.DataModels.CandidateGeographiesAttributes'`

My code follows as below

```
//Able to get result from SP here 
List obj_Candidate_Geographies_List = 
    DBEntity.sp_GetCandidateEntityDataByFunctionTypeIdAndLevel(
        Convert.ToInt32(FunctionTypeEnum.Geography),
        Convert.ToInt32(EntityLevel.Undefined)
    ).ToList();

//Not able to convert to predefined model here 
IQueryable obj_Candidate_Geographies_Attributes_List = 
    (from c in DBEntity.Candidates.ToList() 
        join p in DBEntity.vw_Candidate_AttributesNew.ToList() 
            on c.CandidateId equals p.CandidateId 
        join q in obj_Candidate_Geographies_List 
            on c.CandidateId equals q.CandidateId 
    select new 
            { 
                CandidateId = c.CandidateId, 
                FirstName = q.FirstName, 
                LastName = q.LastName, 
                GeographyId = q.GeographyId, 
                GeographyName = q.GeographyName, 
                SkillId = p.SkillId, 
                SkillName = p.SkillName, 
                CreatedOn = c.CreatedOn, 
                ModifiedOn = c.ModifiedOn 
            }
        );

//Predefined Model
public class CandidateGeographiesAttributes 
{ 
    public int CandidateId { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    public int GeographyId { get; set; } 
    public string GeographyName { get; set; } 
    public int SkillId { get; set; } 
    public string SkillName { get; set; } 
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } 
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; } 
}
```

Could anyone please help me out in how to cast the linq result to list of predefined data model.

Comment: Please spend some time on formatting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be creating instances of `CanidateGeographicAttributes` instead of letting linq create anonymous types for you here:

```
select new { CandidateId = c.CandidateId, FirstNam ...
```

Change to:

```
select new CanidateGeographicAttributes() { CandidateId = c.CandidateId, FirstNam..
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new CandidateGeographiesAttributes instead of an anonymous type. as such:

```
IQueryable<CandidateGeographiesAttributes> 
obj_Candidate_Geographies_Attributes_List = 
(from c in DBEntity.Candidates 

    join p in DBEntity.vw_Candidate_AttributesNew.ToList() on c.CandidateId
    equals  p.CandidateId 

    join q in obj_Candidate_Geographies_List on c.CandidateId 
    equals q.CandidateId 

    select new CandidateGeographiesAttributes
    { 
        CandidateId = c.CandidateId, 
        FirstName = q.FirstName, 
        LastName = q.LastName, 
        GeographyId = q.GeographyId, 
        GeographyName = q.GeographyName, 
        SkillId = p.SkillId, 
        SkillName = p.SkillName, 
        CreatedOn = c.CreatedOn, 
        ModifiedOn = c.ModifiedOn 
    }
).AsQueryable();

//Predefined Model 
public class CandidateGeographiesAttributes 
{ 
public int CandidateId { get; set; } 
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; } 
public int GeographyId { get; set; } 
public string GeographyName { get; set; } 
public int SkillId { get; set; } 
public string SkillName { get; set; } 
public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } 
public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, got compile error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebUI.DataModels.CandidateGeographiesAtt‌​ributes' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable WebUI.DataModels.CandidateGeographiesAttributes'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: change IQueryable to IEnumerable or you should be able to add .AsQueryable() to the end of the linq statement to keep the IQueryable